# No callback when clicking menu item

Tags: objective-c, macos, selector, nsmenu, findersync

I'm trying to implement a simple context menu in my FinderSync extension.

I built the following using some examples, and my problem is that the callback is never called when I click the menu item.

Source code:

**ContextMenuHelper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "FinderSync.h"

@interface ContextMenuHelper : NSObject

+ (NSMenu *)buildMenu;

@end
```

**ContextMenuHelper.m**

```
#import "ContextMenuHelper.h"

#define SharedContextMenuTarget  [ContextMenuTarget sharedInstance]

@interface ContextMenuTarget : NSObject
+ (ContextMenuTarget *) sharedInstance;
@end

@implementation ContextMenuTarget

- (void) callback              : (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called back!!!");
}

+ (ContextMenuTarget *) sharedInstance
{
    static ContextMenuTarget *sharedContextMenuTarget = nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!sharedContextMenuTarget)
            sharedContextMenuTarget = [[ContextMenuTarget alloc] init];
        return sharedContextMenuTarget;
    }
}

@end

@implementation ContextMenuHelper

+ (NSMenu *)buildMenu
{
    ContextMenuTarget *contextMenuTarget = SharedContextMenuTarget;

    NSMenu *mySubmenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

    NSMenuItem *newMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"hello"
                                                     action:@selector(callback:)
                                              keyEquivalent:@""];
    [newMenu setTarget:contextMenuTarget];
    [mySubmenu addItem:newMenu];

    return mySubmenu;
}

@end
```

**MyFinderSync.m**

```
...
- (NSMenu *)menuForMenuKind:(FIMenuKind)whichMenu {

    NSMenu *myContextMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

    @try
    {
        if(whichMenu != FIMenuKindContextualMenuForItems) {
            return myContextMenu;
        }

        myContextMenu = [ContextMenuHelper buildMenu];
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex)
    {
    }

    return myContextMenu;
}
...
```

Comment: I found the following example: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity/blob/29650642dea00ea491d906871c285c2b50170758/mac/FinderSync/LiferayFinderSync/RequestManager.m#L149 looks much more complicated than my try. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, callbacks will only work if the target is the instance of `FinderSync`. Could not find any documentation to support this theory, but the only thing that fixed the problem was moving the context menu code into **MyFinderSync.m**:

```
...
- (NSMenu *)menuForMenuKind:(FIMenuKind)whichMenu {

    NSMenu *myContextMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

    @try
    {
        if(whichMenu != FIMenuKindContextualMenuForItems) {
            return myContextMenu;
        }

        myContextMenu = [self buildMenu];
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex)
    {
    }

    return myContextMenu;
}

- (NSMenu *)buildMenu
{
    NSMenu *mySubmenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

    NSMenuItem *newMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"hello"
                                                     action:@selector(callback:)
                                              keyEquivalent:@""];
    [newMenu setTarget:self];
    [mySubmenu addItem:newMenu];

    return mySubmenu;
}

- (void) callback              : (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called back!!!");
}
...
```